# Relationship between views with shared string field been used as id

Tags: views, 8

**Issue**: (*Updated issue description*) I need to list all properties where their `field_development_ref` value matches the new_homes_development content types' `field_development_ref`. The view will be embedded within the new_homes_development node, and that nodes matching properties will be listed at the bottom.

I wanted to create a view with a block pane that will have the node ID contextual filter and then related all properties that share the same `field_development_ref` value. When I go to the relationships section under advanced I see no ability to related one to the other.

Content type - Property

```
Fields of interest:
- field_development_ref
```

> Note: This content types data is imported from an external datasource
>   that has no knowledge of the Drupal system via an API.

Content type - New development

```
Fields of interest:
- field_development_ref
```

Notes:

- Several properties imported may belong to a new_home_development node, like a gated community (*the new_home_development*) with sub plots (*the properties*) and if this is the case they will carry the same Development ID stored within `field_development_ref`
- The New homes development content type is created manually by a content editor. When filling out the node information they will get the developments ID and put it in the `field_development_ref` field.

How can I relate one to the other?

The view I have currently is shown below along with the content types in question.

**View - Content using new_home_development content type**
[image: View]

**Content type "new_home_development" fields**
[image: new_home_development content type fields]

**Content type "property" fields (Partial)**
[image]

Comment: Your configuration is clear enough, thank you for the detas and screenshots. But the issue isn't. I think you're confusing it with the node id. What content exactly do you want to list, and on what pages, with which connections? Do you want to list new development nodes on Project pages, but only those that share the same development ref field? Or vice versa? Or somethng else? It's better if you just first describe the problem without making assumptions about technicalities, then add those if you have any.

Comment: I have update the issue/requirements of what I am trying to do.

Comment: This would be easy to do if your Development ref field was a reference to a Taxonomy term. It is very common to display sibling content (that share the same terms). But with a text field, the Relationship isn't available in Views so they can't easily be compared. You can probably do it by creating a custom Contextual filter that compares the text values. https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/how-create-custom-views-argument-plugin-drupal-8 If you don't want to do custom code the best is to create a Vocabulary with Development ref terms and use Entity reference field to those instead of a text field.

Comment: @prkos Yea I realised this would be done easiest without using a view at all and writing a custom module to simply run a DB API query to get the properties I need. This way I avoid having to write code in the API itself to automatically add taxonomy terms. Cheers for the patience and answers.